# Banach isomorphisms between von Neumann algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

It seems that most people are talking about $*$-isomorphisms of von Neumann algebras. However, I can not find any references for the Banach isomorphisms, i.e., let $A,B$ be two different von Neumann algebras (consider them as Banach spaces equipped with uniform norms), are there any bijective mapping from $A$ onto $B$? In particular, I would like to consider the case when $A$ is a finite von Neumann algebra and $B=B(H)$.

Comment: Could you be more specific? It seems like the particular case $A$ finite and $B=B(H)$ is trivially answered in the negative. The set of bounded linear operators on a nontrivial Hilbert is always uncountable infinite, so there is no hope for a bijection with a finite set.

Comment: @Nick I mean, A is a finite von Neumann algebra.

Comment: If you're willing to generalize to C*-algebras, then it's known that there are non-$*$-isomorphic C*-algebras that are isometrically isomorphic as Banach spaces, but it doesn't seem like your question is settled in general (see the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156621/when-are-two-c-algebras-isomorphic-as-banach-spaces)).  I'm guessing it's subtle/unknown for von Neumann algebras as well, but I wonder whether the existence of a Banach space predual changes anything.  Any von Neumann algebra, taken as a Banach space, has a predual (unique up to isometric isomorphism).

Comment: @JoshKeneda Thx! Ozawa mentioned a result in mathoverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448745/banach-isomorphisms-between-von-neumann-algebras?noredirect=1#comment1159546_448745

Comment: Oh, that’s awesome!